# Pass SIGTSTP signal to all processes in a job in LSF

Tags: perl, lsf

The problem statement in short: Is there a way in LSF to pass a signal SIGCONT/SIGTSTP to all processes running within a job?

I have a Perl wrapper script that runs on LSF (Version 9.1.2) and starts a tool (Source not available) on the same LSF machine as the Perl script.

The tool starts 2 processes, one for license management and another for doing the actual work. It also supports an option where sending SIGSTSP/SIGCONT to both processes will release/reacquire the license (which is what I wish to achieve).

Running `bkill -s SIGCONT <JOB_ID>` only resumes the tool process and not the license process, which is a problem.

I tried to see if I can send the signals to the Perl script's own PGID, but the license process starts its own process group.

Any suggestions to move forward through Perl or LSF options are welcome.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Some additional information: I am running on RHEL6, with Perl 5.16.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to see if I can send the signals to the Perl script's own PGID, *but the license process starts its own process group.*

This is likely your problem right here.  LSF keeps track of "processes running within the job" by process group.  If your job spawns a process that runs within its own process group (say by daemonizing itself) then it essentially is a runaway process out of LSF's control -- it becomes your job's responsibility to manage it.

For reference, see the section on "Detached processes" [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.2/lsf_admin/troubleshooting_common_problems_lsf.html?lang=en).

As for options:

1. I think the cgroups tracking functionality helps in a lot of these cases, you can ask your admin if `LSF_PROCESS_TRACKING` and `LSF_LINUX_CGROUP_ACCT` are set in lsf.conf.  If they aren't, then you can ask him to set them and see if that helps for your case (you need to make sure the host you're running on supports cgroups).  In 9.1.2 this feature is turned on at installation time, so this option might not actually help you for various reasons (your hosts don't have cgroups enabled for example).
2. Manage the license process yourself.  If you can find out the PID/PGID of the license process from within your `perl` script, you can install custom signal handlers for `SIGCONT`/`SIGSTP` in your script using `sigtrap` or the like and forward them to the license process yourself when your script receives them through `bkill`.  See [here](http://perltricks.com/article/37/2013/8/18/Catch-and-Handle-Signals-in-Perl).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is useful information. I will check with my LSF admin about LSF settings you suggest. Meanwhile, I will also explore ways to track processes through session IDs in Perl as I see every process for a given job has same session ID.